# How can I stack a div with a box-shadow on top of another div with a box-shadow property

Tags: html, css

I need to stack the two divs on top of one another.But when I try to do so,their shadows combine together underneath to form a rectangular shape.

```
.wrap-header {
min-height: 94px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #bfbfbf;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #bfbfbf;
}

aside {
float: right;
height: 700px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 4px #bfbfbf;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 4px #bfbfbf;
width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ycS2c/)

```
.wrap-header {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 94px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #bfbfbf;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #bfbfbf;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #bfbfbf;
}

aside {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 700px;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 3px #bfbfbf;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 3px #bfbfbf;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 3px #bfbfbf;
}
```